# Add on a column to each table while webscraping with rvest

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I'm trying to scrape the last five dates on this [webpage](http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date=2019-03-24). Here I have `seq_dates_test` (the sequence of Dates I want to scrape on that webpage):

`structure(c(17975, 17976, 17977, 17978, 17979), class = "Date")`

I'm using the below code chunk to successfully scrape these dates

```
url <- "http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date="

url %>% 
  map2_chr(seq_dates_test,paste0) %>% 
  map_df(. %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes("table") %>% 
    html_table(header = TRUE) %>%
    # Extract out first element of list
    magrittr::extract2(1)
    )
```

However, I'd like to `mutate` a Date column for each table (corresponding to each date). I've tried to add on `mutate(Date = seq_dates_test)` after the `extract2`, but  I get this error...

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `Date` must be length 285 (the number of rows) or one, not 5

---

UPDATE: How would I change my code so that if table X is length 0, I skip that table and move on to scraping the next table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized, so we don't need to do a `map2`.  We can directly `paste` the 'url' with the dates and extract the table and use the `.id` to create a column 'Date' by having a named `vector`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map_df(set_names(paste0(url, seq_dates_test), seq_dates_test), ~
      .x %>% 
         read_html() %>% 
         html_nodes("table") %>% 
         html_table(header = TRUE) %>%    
         magrittr::extract2(1), .id = 'Date')

dim(out)
#[1] 1365    6

head(out)
#        Date     Time                                                         Event                               Address     Responding Agency
#1 2019-03-20 23:51:00                                             Parking complaint              1398 DEWEY AV, Rochester Rochester City Police
#2 2019-03-20 23:12:00 Dangerous condition - no immediate danger to life or property        2970 W HENRIETTA RD, Henrietta  Monroe County Police
#3 2019-03-20 22:50:00                                                 Odor of smoke          2349 E RIDGE RD, Irondequoit     Ridge Culver Fire
#4 2019-03-20 22:44:00                                           Dangerous condition          DENISE RD/LAKE AV, Rochester Rochester City Police
#5 2019-03-20 22:00:00                                             Parking complaint               3150 W RIDGE RD, Greece         Greece Police
#6 2019-03-20 21:58:00           Accident of motor vehicles involving unknown injury SB RT 590 AT BROWNCROFT BL, Rochester New York State Police
#       Event ID
#1 CTYP190793429
#2 MCOP190793334
#3 RCUF190793284
#4 CTYP190793264
#5 GREP190793188
#6 NYSP190793186
```

#### Update

If we need to have an error-check and return a default value, either `tryCatch` or `possibly` from `purrr` can be used

```
f1 <- function(x) {
        x %>%
           read_html() %>% 
           html_nodes("table") %>% 
           html_table(header = TRUE) %>%    
           magrittr::extract2(1)


}            
pos1 <- possibly(f1, otherwise = NULL, quiet = TRUE)

outlst1 <- map(set_names(paste0(url, seq_dates_test), 
                  seq_dates_test), pos1, .id = 'Date')
```

and then filter out the `NULL` elements

```
bind_rows(discard(outlst1, is.null))
```

#### data

```
seq_dates_test <- structure(c(17975, 17976, 17977, 17978, 17979), class = "Date")
url <- "http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date="
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does this `mutate` a Date column for each table?

Comment: Do you mind looking at my additional question? I added it to my original post. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonBalk  I think you may need `tryCatch` if there is any error i.e. within the code,, you can `tryCatch({.x %>% ..}, error = function(e) return NULL)`  and then use `discard(out, is.null)`

Comment: I just upvoted your question and accepted it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in your flow, since we want to add a new column of `Date` for every dataframe we can `map` over `seq_dates_test` instead of the pasted urls.

```
library(rvest)

map(seq_dates_test, function(x) 
         paste0(url, x) %>%
               read_html() %>% 
               html_nodes("table") %>% 
               html_table(header = TRUE) %>%
               magrittr::extract2(1) %>%
               mutate(Date = x))
```

**data**

```
seq_dates_test <- structure(c(17975, 17976, 17977, 17978, 17979), class = "Date")
url <- "http://mcsafetyfeed.org/incidents.php?date="
```

Comment: Do you mind looking at my additional question? I added it to my original post.  Thank you!